# Переключение между checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Есть много чекбоксов независимых друг от друга. И есть 2 чекбокса: `id="Bort"` и `id="Borta"` которые работают по принципу радиобаттонов, при этом можно не выбрать ни одного чекбокса из этой пары.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также есть два радиобаттона `id="radio"` и `id="radio2"`.

Итого получается шесть возможных комбинации по выбору чекбоксов и радиобаттонов

1. не выбран ни один чекбокс, выбран первый радиобаттон
2. не выбран ни один чекбокс, выбран второй радиобаттон
3. выбран первый чекбокс, выбран первый радиобаттон
4. выбран первый чекбокс, выбран второй радиобаттон
5. выбран второй чекбокс, выбран первый радиобаттон
6. выбран второй чекбокс, выбран второй радиобаттон

Каждой этой комбинации соответствует своя картинка

```
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="Борт"  id="Bort">Борт у стены
<input type="checkbox"  class="radio" name="Борта"  id="Borta" >Борта у стены
<input class="kartinki" name="гор планки" type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" id="Gor_planki" />гор планки
<br>
<input class="kartinki" name="Лестница" type="radio" id="radio" value="слева" checked="checked" />
слева
<input class="kartinki" type="radio" name="Лестница" id="radio2" value="справа" />справа
<br>

<img src="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/krovat-cherdak-s-rabochej-zonoj_i_stolom_527.jpg" id="image" width="310" height="280" />
```

Вопрос: как реализовать работу чекбоксов в режиме радиобаттонов и при этом обеспечить смену картинок?

Накидала код, не совсем то что мне нужно получилось, Борт и Борта должны переключаться между собой:

```
    $('input').on("click",function(){

if($('#Bort').prop('checked') && $('#radio').prop('checked')) { 
    $('#Borta').prop('checked', false);//пытаюсь отключить Борта

 $('#image').attr('src','http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/krovat-cherdak-s-rabochej-zonoj_527_2.jpg');//бортa,леваяЛестница
  } 
  else if($('#Bort').prop('checked') && $('#radio2').prop('checked')) { 
      $('#image').attr('src','http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/ecoskarb.ru_bed_attic_860.jpg');//бортa,праваяЛестница
  } 

  else if($('#Borta').prop('checked') && $('#radio').prop('checked')) { 
   $('#Bort').prop('checked', false); //пытаюсь отключить Борт  
  $('#image').attr('src','http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/krovat_cherdachok_750.jpg');//бортa,леваяЛестница
  } 
  else if($('#Borta').prop('checked') && $('#radio2').prop('checked')) { 
      $('#image').attr('src','http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/krovat_cherdak_527.jpg');//бортa,праваяЛестница
  } 
   else if($('#Gor_planki').prop('checked') && $('#radio').prop('checked')) { 
      $('#image').attr('src','http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/bed_attic_2.jpg');//горПланки,леваяЛестница
  } 
  else if($('#Gor_planki').prop('checked') && $('#radio2').prop('checked')) { 
      $('#image').attr('src','http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/bed_attic_2.jpg');//горПланки,праваяЛестница
  } 

  })
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как сделать переключение чекбоксов. Нужно именно через id.

> Полный код:
>   [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/29298/)

Comment: А почему не использовать radiobutton?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov добавила картинку,много чекбоксов,где нужно 2 чекбокса переключать между собой

Comment: Они могут быть выключены оба?

Comment: @Лиана, Дайте весь блок с чекбоксами, должен быть выбран только 1? И вообще для этих целей есть радио кнопки, которые могут быть стилизованы под чекбоксы, а уже понял именно борта...

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov выключать оба не надо

Comment: Пользователь может не выбрать ни один из этих двух чекбоксов? Или он **обязательно** должен что-то выбрать?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov  может и не выбирать их)

Comment: @Лиана Вы не внимательны. У моих чекбоксов **два** класса `kartinki`  и `radio`

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov простите,поправила,но что-то не так...

Comment: @Лиана Давайте Вы **внятно** сформулируете задачу. А то вначале были два чекбокса, а сейчас чекбоксы, радиобаттоны, картинки...

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Извините, думала что без этих подробностей получится))) Поправила описание. Посмотрите, пожалуиста, понятно ли?

Comment: @Лиана Я отредактировал Ваш вопрос. Посмотрите, я правильно его понял?

Comment: Добавьте еще один вариант "Без бортов" и сделайте три инпута про борты - радио-кнопками.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю будет понятно, дальше доработаете под свои нужды.

```js
$('#Bort').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    if ($('#Borta').prop('checked')) {
      $('#Borta').prop('checked', false);
    }

    if ($('#radio').prop('checked')) {
      $('#image').attr('src', 'http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/krovat-cherdak-s-rabochej-zonoj_527_2.jpg');
    } else if ($('#radio2').prop('checked')) {
      $('#image').attr('src', 'http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/ecoskarb.ru_bed_attic_860.jpg');
    }
  }
});


$('#Borta').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    if ($('#Bort').prop('checked')) {
      $('#Bort').prop('checked', false);
    }

    if ($('#radio').prop('checked')) {
      $('#image').attr('src', 'http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/krovat_cherdachok_750.jpg');
    } else if ($('#radio2').prop('checked')) {
      $('#image').attr('src', 'http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/krovat_cherdak_527.jpg');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="Борт" id="Bort">Борт у стены
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="Борта" id="Borta">Борта у стены
<input class="kartinki" name="гор планки" type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" id="Gor_planki" />гор планки
<br>
<input class="kartinki" name="Лестница" type="radio" id="radio" value="слева" checked="checked" /> слева
<input class="kartinki" type="radio" name="Лестница" id="radio2" value="справа" />справа
<br>

<img src="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/krovat-cherdak-s-rabochej-zonoj_i_stolom_527.jpg" id="image" width="310" height="280" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov попробовала ваши скрипты,отдельно они работают, но не в моем коде, так как идет привязка к картинкам. Когда вставляла то что вы мне написали, переключение срабатывает, но не меняется картинка. Поэтому думаю нужно их вместе прописывать переключение и смена картинок.Если не сложно можете посмотреть на код выше я его обновила и выложила https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/29298/

Comment: @Лиана, Посмотрите теперь (изменил ответ).

Comment: #radio2 не работает.

Comment: @Лиана, Как не работает? Вы нажмите выполнить код и проверьте там...

Comment: @Лиана, Если вы имеете ввиду, что сразу не переключает (без клика на чекбокс), после выбора слева, или справа, то просто допишите данный функционал.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  // Цепляем обработчик на все нужные элементы
  $('.radio').change(function() {
    // У всех элементов, кроме кликнутого, снимаем пометку
    $('.radio').not(this).prop({checked: false});
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  Борт
  <input type="checkbox" class="kartinki radio" name="Борт" id="Bort">
</label>
<label>
  Борта
  <input type="checkbox" class="kartinki radio" name="Борта" id="Borta">
</label>
<label>
  Что-то еще
  <input type="checkbox" class="kartinki" name="Other" id="Other">
</label>
```